# Convert and parse data string

Tags: c#, string, parsing, hex, type-conversion

I am pretty new to C#. What I would like to do is the following:

Take a string (in my code it is `rawData`), parse it according to the following format:

1) First two characters are PGN data length in hex, i.e. `0B` == 11 which is the length of piece (3) described below.

2) Characters 2 through 6 isthe PGN number in hex, i.e. `00FEE9` == 65257

3) Characters 6 through (6 + `Convert.ToInt32(0B)`) found in step 1 is the data in hex.

I know I need to do the following:
a) parse the string and convert the characters from hex to decimal.
b) split each segment when the string has a few instances of combinations of data (multiple segments of 1,2,3 in one message).

I tried using `int.Parse` and `Convert.ToInt32` but to no avail.

This is my code so far:

```
string rawData = "*TS01,351581053233312,194027161216,GPS:3;N36.397814;W82.483871;13;104;1.35,STT:242;0,MGR:107,ADC:0;13.68;1;23.33;2;3.89"+
            "CAN:0B00FEE9B4D8040020D604000B00FEE86932F50CFFFF5C5D0B00FEE00100FFFFFFE0FE000B00FEE50100FFFFFFE5FE00,EGT:4409,EVT:1#";

string rawData1 = "*TS01,351581053233312,194027161216,GPS:3;N36.397814;W82.483871;13;104;1.35,STT:242;0,MGR:107,ADC:0;13.68;1;23.33;2;3.89" +
            "CAN:0B00FEE9B4D8040020D60400,EGT:4409,EVT:1#";

int CANindex = rawData.IndexOf("CAN:");

string CANmessage = rawData1.Substring(CANindex + 4);
string CANmessage1 = CANmessage.Split(',').First();

Console.WriteLine("CANMessage1: " + CANmessage1);
/*Console.WriteLine("CANmessage1.Substring(0, 2): " + CANmessage1.Substring(0, 2));*/

string pgnDataLength = CANmessage1.Substring(0, 2);
char[] pgnDataLengthArray = pgnDataLength.ToCharArray();

string pgnNumber = CANmessage1.Substring(2, 6);
char[] pgnNumberArray = pgnNumber.ToCharArray();

Console.WriteLine("pgnDataLength: " + pgnDataLength);
Console.WriteLine("pgnNumber: " + pgnNumber);

/*int hexvalue = int.Parse(pgnString);
Console.WriteLine("hexvalue: " + hexvalue);
*/
/*
int PGNDataLength = Convert.ToInt32(CANmessage1.Substring(0, 2));
Console.WriteLine("PGNDataLength: " + PGNDataLength);
*/
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

or

int decValue = Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 16);

Answer (score -1):

Got it!

```
int pgnDataLength = Convert.ToInt32(pgnDataLengthStr, 16);
int pgnNumber = Convert.ToInt32(pgnNumberStr, 16);
```

Comment: What is `pgnDataLengthStr` or `pgnNumberStr` ?

Comment: You can mark my answer as right one.. Have i explained something different??

Comment: @L.B string pgnNumberStr = CANmessage1.Substring(2, 6) and string pgnDataLengthStr = CANmessage1.Substring(0, 2);